# I have been denied an Australian travel visa

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, australia

I have applied for a travel visa to Australia and have been denied. I got a reference # to inquire further, but can not seem to find any way to contact someone or enter the said reference # for and further help. What do I do? I already purchased my flights.

Comment: On what grounds was your visa application refused?

Answer (score 7):

In the future, it is not recommended to buy flight tickets before your visa is granted to avoid similar situations. If you bought a refundable ticket you can try and get a refund for your flight, this is the easier option rather than appealing the visa.

If not, you can appeal the decision using a service/guide like this one [here](https://www.legalaid.vic.gov.au/find-legal-answers/migration/appealing-visa-decision). Getting a refund for your flight ticket will depend upon whether or not you purchased a ticket which is refundable. Even with a non-refundable ticket, it may also be possible to reschedule your flights to a later date and time.

Or as *Traveller* mentioned, another cheaper and faster option is to re-apply since there is no minimum time to wait before applying again. The new application must address the reason for refusal though, for example significant change in personal circumstances, or you will be refused again.